# Flutter: Courier has no Unicode support error

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, fonts

I'm trying to use a font family NunitoSans & I have to modify a pre existing app. This is what the pubspec.yaml file looks like in terms of the font:

```
    flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: NunitoSans
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/NunitoSans-Regular.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: fonts/NunitoSans-ExtraLight.ttf
          weight: 100
        - asset: fonts/NunitoSans-Light.ttf
          weight: 200
        - asset: fonts/NunitoSans-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: fonts/NunitoSans-Bold.ttf
          weight: 800
        - asset: fonts/NunitoSans-ExtraBold.ttf
          weight: 900
    - family: OverpassMono
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/OverpassMono-Regular.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: fonts/OverpassMono-Light.ttf
          weight: 100
    - family: AppIcons
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/AppIcons.ttf
          weight: 500
    

  assets:
    - assets/QR.svg
    - assets/welcome_animation.flr
    - assets/send_animation.flr
```

And this is how I'm trying to use the font. If I put anything other than fonts/NunitoSans-Regualar.ttf I get an error that this font is not present in the desired location.

```
final font1 = await rootBundle.load('fonts/NunitoSans-Regular.ttf');

final font2 = await rootBundle.load('fonts/NunitoSans-Regular.ttf');
```

Any help is appreciated. This is my full error (the link did not help me sorry):

```
Courier has no Unicode support see https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/wiki/Fonts-Management

 The font is not in my assets, its like this:
```

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3q32.png)

Comment: Since Courier isn't listed in any of your font choices, it must get used when the requested font is not found.

Comment: any ideas on how to find the requested font?

Comment: Just make sure it's installed in your system.

Comment: its installed which is why i cant figure out why i cant access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  fonts:
- family: Montserrat
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf
- family: MontserratMedium
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/MontserratMedium-Medium.ttf    
- family: MontserratLight
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/MontserratLight-Light.otf    
- family: OpenSans  
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
- family: Palatino
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/Palatino-Italic.ttf
```

In Widget use like this

```
 TextStyle(
fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
color: Colors.white,
fontSize: 28,
fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
//fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
letterSpacing: 2,
);

TextStyle(
fontFamily: 'MontserratMedium',
color: Colors.white,
fontSize: 17,
letterSpacing: 0,
);
```

Comment: i need to use it like final font1 = await rootBundle.load('fonts/NunitoSans-Regular.ttf');
Can't change that part